# Laravel 5 and AngularJS removing '#' from url

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

Im at the moment building an application where i want my urls to be like `my-domain.com/` instead of `my-domain.com/#/`. Because I'm building an SPA with AngularJS, I enabled the `html5Mode` of the `$locationProvider`.

However, when i go to another page like `my-domain.com/test` (defined in my `$routeProvider` config), I get laravel's error page. This is not what i want because i want AngularJS to handle this route.

I looked around and found things like

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return view('client/index');
});
```

which sadly dont work in Laravel 5. After researching the new way to handle errors, I decided to test the new Exception Handler, so in my App\Exceptions\Handler.php I did this:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        return view('client/index');
    }
```

Unfortunately, this also doesnt work because now it renders a blank page...

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Here is my code of my angular ngroute config:

```
client.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/client_partials/Homepage.html'
        })
        .when('/test', {
            templateUrl: '/client_partials/Homepage.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo : '/'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

Comment: reconfigure your htaccess so any non asset or api requests are pointed to app entry point

Answer (score 7):

Here is the route:

```
Route::any('{path?}', function()
{
    return File::get(public_path() . '/angular.html');
})->where("path", ".+");
```

Comment: This will cause the page to refresh, totally negating any benefit of a single-page JS app. You can achieve this with .htaccess, no other routes are necessary.

Comment: This worked for me, except I use view() to present the view, thanks!